# What do I need to know when using Replace in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

**I really want to be be cautious when doing my job.**

I need to replace blank with some text in my SQL Query but I don't want actually update into database, just want to update to data I query.

If I use `Replace()` will it replace on server too or just to data I query?

can you provide me with example, how I can use Replace() to replace only in data I read not into server.

Comment: "In Oracle/PLSQL, the replace function replaces a sequence of characters in a string with another set of characters." [source](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php) also see CASE and COALESCE etc. `SELECT replace(name, "mo", "") AS foo FROM names;` which would return the field `name` from the table `names` with `mo` replaced with "" as its a `SELECT` statement then it alters the data returned by the query not the actual data you'd do that by using an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: As a general rule, _always_ run a query that will update the DB as a `select` first to check that you haven't made a stupid mistake.

Comment: a SELECT will not update the data in the database, you'd have to explicitly use UPDATE statement to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How you use `REPLACE` has nothing to do with updating data.

Rather, it is whether you use a `SELECT` or `UPDATE` statement that matters.

A [`SELECT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm) statement will only query (retrieve) data, it will not modify it in the database.

Oracle Docs:

> Use a SELECT statement or subquery to retrieve data from one or more
>   tables, object tables, views, object views, or materialized views.

An [`UPDATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708) statement will modify the data in the database, assuming it finds matching rows.

Oracle Docs:

> Use the UPDATE statement to change existing values in a table or in
>   the base table of a view or the master table of a materialized view.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`Replace()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php) in a `SELECT` then it will only replace it in your query.

`SELECT` version, this will replace any blank spaces in your field with no space in the data you return:

```
SELECT replace(yourField, ' ', '')
FROM yourtable
```

If you use `Replace()` in an `UPDATE` then you will be updating it in the server.

`UPDATE` version, this will update all values in your field to replace any blank spaces:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET yourfield = replace(yourField, ' ', '')
```